# Joining data from two vector members of a list

Tags: r

I have these assignment instructions.

Print, on each line, each name followed by “|”, followed by the age. **Create a list where members are two vectors**. The first vector holds the first names. **The members of the list** should have the names - "first names" and "ages". Output this list in the following format.

If I'm not mistaken, three things are required for the setup. A list containing two vectors.

```
first_names <- c("Jim", "Frank", "Sally")
ages <- c("25", "34", "42")
list_data <- list(first_names, ages)

# Desired Output
Jim   | 25
Frank | 34
Sally | 42
```

I am able to accomplish this with using just two vectors but not when they are included in a list. Am I understanding the instructions correctly?

My version with only two vectors works.

```
first_names <- c("Jim", "Frank", "Sally")
ages <- c("25", "34", "42")

if (length(first_names) == length(ages)) {
  for (i in 1:length(first_names)) {
    print(paste(first_names[i],ages[i],sep = " | "))
  } 
} else {
  print("Error")
}
```

But the version with the list is where I need help.

```
first_names <- c("Jim", "Frank", "Sally")
ages <- c("25", "34", "42")
list_data <- list(first_names, ages) # list

if (length(list_data[1]) == length(list_data[2])) {
  for (i in 1:length(list_data[1])) {
    print(paste(list_data[1][i],list_data[2][i],sep = " | "))
  } 
} else {
  print("Error")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized you don't need `for` loop here.

```
cat(paste(first_names, ages, sep = " | ", collapse = '\n'))

#Jim | 25
#Frank | 34
#Sally | 42
```

If you want to use these tables in some reports there are better ways available with `kable` or similar packages.

---

If we want to use `list_data` we can do :

```
cat(paste(list_data[[1]], list_data[[2]], sep = " | ", collapse = '\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks. But as per instructions I have to create a list of the two vectors. In my question I have `list_data <- list(first_names, ages)`

Comment: Thanks @Ronak for the update. That's what I am looking for because it simply prints it out with no vector symbols etc. And it is also beginner level where were are taught cat/paste before being taught other more advanced functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
library( data.table )
lapply( data.table::transpose(list_data), paste0, collapse = "|" )


[[1]]
[1] "Jim|25"

[[2]]
[1] "Frank|34"

[[3]]
[1] "Sally|42"
```

Comment: Thanks Wimpel. We haven't got into `data.table` yet. I will take notes on how to use transpose like in your answer. Would it be possible for you to add another version that does not use data.table? A more beginner friendly version.

Comment: data.table is actually beginner-friendly... but you will have to wrap your head around the filosofy of it.... and then you can see the matrix ;-)

Comment: Yes it is beginner friendly. I love it. However, we haven't used it yet. Can this be done another way?

Comment: Ronak's answer is exactly what my instructor was looking for. I upvoted your answer  anyway because it's a nice solution that I will definitely use in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` with `paste`.

```
mapply(paste, list_data[1], list_data[2], sep = " | ")
#     [,1]        
#[1,] "Jim | 25"  
#[2,] "Frank | 34"
#[3,] "Sally | 42"
```

Or without lines and cols using `writeLines`:

```
writeLines(mapply(paste, list_data[1], list_data[2], sep = " | "))
#writeLines(paste(list_data[[1]], list_data[[2]], sep = " | ")) #Alternative
#Jim | 25
#Frank | 34
#Sally | 42
```

Or with your code adapted using `[[` instead of `[`:

```
if (length(list_data[1]) == length(list_data[2])) {
  for (i in 1:length(list_data[[1]])) {
    writeLines(paste(list_data[[1]][i],list_data[[2]][i],sep = " | "))
  } 
} else {
  print("Error")
}
#Jim | 25
#Frank | 34
#Sally | 42
```

Or using `sprintf` to reproduce the desired ouptup:

```
writeLines(sprintf(paste0("%-", max(nchar(list_data[[1]])), "s", " | %s"),
 list_data[[1]], list_data[[2]]))
Jim   | 25
Frank | 34
Sally | 42
```

Comment: Thanks GKi. These work very well and I will paste them into my notebook. They output quite a few vector symbols etc whereas Ronak's solution above outputs just the data. It is exactly what my instructor is looking for. I will upvote your answer of course.

Comment: In case you don't want line and col numbers just use in addition `writeLines` like shown in the update.

Comment: Wow that's cool. I've never seen that before. I will use that in the future. If I use writeLines with mapply now my instructor will know it's not from me lol Thank you very much.

Comment: You can also use `writeLines(paste(list_data[[1]], list_data[[2]], sep = " | "))`

Comment: Thank you. It's great to get so much info in one Stack question.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can use inbuilt function `paste` or `paste0` in R.
Nothing else required

```
paste0(first_names,"|",ages)
```

The above code will print you the desired result.

To store it in a list , you can use

```
as.list(paste0(first_names,"|",ages))
```

Comment: Thanks. But as per instructions I have to create a list of the two vectors. In my question I have `list_data <- list(first_names, ages)`